# How to show only certain rows from a table in my DB?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, forum

I am creating a message board in PHP using Zend Framework and phpMyAdmin (MySQL). I'm a beginner with Zend Framework and haven't done much in PHP, so please be as simplistic as possible in your answers.

I've saved the structure of the message board (sections, under-sections and under-under-sections) in the database. I need to display the sections of the forum and their corresponding underSections. The question is - how do I display the under-sections of a particular section under it?

`IndexController.php`:

```
 public function indexAction()
{
    $sections = new Model_Sections();
    $this->view->sections = $sections->fetchAll();

    $undersections = new Model_Undersections();
    $this->view->undersections = $undersections->fetchAll();
}
```

In this code I fetch all the section and undersection data (id & name).

Database model `Section.php`:

```
class Model_Sections extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'sections';
}
```

Database model `Undersection.php`:

```
class Model_Undersections extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'undersections';
}
```

Fragment from the main view "index.phtml" concerning output of data:

```
<div class="section">
   <?php foreach($this->sections as $sections) : ?>

   <!-- Generates names of sections -->
   <h1><?php echo $this->escape($sections->section_name);?></h1>

      <!-- Generates names of undersections -->
      <?php foreach($this->undersections as $undersections) : ?>
         <div class="underSection">
            <h2>
              <a href=" ***link to some controller according to the undersection*** ">
                 <?php echo $this->escape($undersections->undersection_name);?>
              </a>
            </h2>
         </div>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
 </div>
```

Currently it displays all undersections under every section.

Comment: what is your database structure? you currently don't have anything that links sections with undersections

Comment: Sections table has a primary key "section_id", which is a foreign key in the undersections table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code currently is displaying all undersections under each section is because you use a nested for-loop in which the inner loop is always the same. I.e. you are always iterating over the same collection of undersections. You need to define a way for the sections and undersections to have a parent-child relationship.

Here is how I would roughly structure it:

DB structure (table name: sections):

```
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
parentId INT DEFAULT 0
section_name TINYTEXT
```

So the data for *all* sections would live in the same database table. When you insert a top level section, you would simply leave the parentId column = 0. When you insert an undersection, you would insert the id value of the parent section.

I would also change your model so that you don't have a Model_Section and an Model_Undersection. Instead, have a function within the Model_Section class called e.g. getChildren() which would return to you a collection of all sections that belong to that particular Model_Section instance.

Controller action:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $sections = new Model_Sections();
    $this->view->sections = $sections->fetchAll();
}
```

View script:

```
<div class="section">
   <?php foreach($this->sections as $sections) : ?>

   <!-- Generates names of sections -->
   <h1><?php echo $this->escape($sections->section_name);?></h1>

      <!-- Generates names of undersections -->
      <?php foreach($sections->getChildren() as $undersections) : ?>
         <div class="underSection">
            <h2>
              <a href=" ***link to some controller according to the undersection*** ">
                 <?php echo $this->escape($undersections->section_name);?>
              </a>
            </h2>
         </div>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
 </div>
```

Note the change in using $sections->getChildren() instead of $this->undersections

The biggest benefit you get from this is that your model now is completely recursive. Your undersections can have child sections of their own, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Jens! I will try it out and leave my feedback here.

I have a question about your proposed DB structure. Shouldn't it also have a sectionID field?

`id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
parentId INT DEFAULT 0
sectionId INT
section_name TINYTEXT`

Comment: I don't really get what the getChildren() function would do. Would you, please, care to explain?

Comment: getChildren should really be done in the controller, rather than the view, surely.

Comment: @Artiso The id column would be the same as the sectionId, so just name id to sectionId if that makes it clearer. getChildren() would return all sections that belong to a certain parent section, e.g. in the database have parentId=1.

Comment: @KasiaGogolek I'd say in the end that's a matter of preference in this case. On one hand for sure the view should know as little as possible about the model, but on the other hand you need to define that structure somewhere anyway and provide it to the view. You could rebuild the tree structure in the controller and then feed it to the view as an associative array e.g., but the view would still need to know the structure in order to output it properly. But perhaps I'm missing something fundamental?

Answer (score 1):

You should set what columns you want to select:

```
class Model_Sections extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'sections';
    public function getSections()
    {
        $select = $this->select()
            ->from($this->_name, array('col1', 'col2')); // set your columns
        return $this->fetchAll($select);
    }
}
```

And in controller:

```
$sections = new Model_Sections();
$this->view->sections = $sections->getSections();
```